# Laravel foreach same record multiple

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to take our some info from mysql with laravel.
My controller:

```
$match->message = DB::table('log')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->get(['message']);

$match->authid = DB::table('log')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->get(['authid']);
```

My blade:

```
 @foreach ($match->authid as $username)
@foreach ($match->message as $text)
{{ $username->authid }} {{ $text->message }}<br />
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

But getting 4 results incorrectly. Getting:

- AUTHD_ID1 log1
- AUTHD_ID1 log2
- AUTHD_ID2 log1
- AUTHD_ID2 log2

Should be:

- AUTHD_ID1 log1
- AUTHD_ID2 log2

Whats wrong?

Comment: Why not `get(['message', 'authid'])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is being duplicated since you have a foreach within a foreach.

Try the code below.

```
$matches = DB::table('log')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->get();

@foreach ($matches as $match)
{{ $match->authid }} {{ $match->message }}<br />
@endforeach`
```

Comment: Your code works great! U made me on the right road! Thanks! Another question: I have users table with row called 'auth_id' and 'username'. How can i convert to auth_id to username? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by converting auth_id into username?

Comment: Example: Users table has row called 'auth_id' and 'username'. My table 'log' also have row called 'auth_id'. I need to find same 'auth_id' on users table and get username by that 'auth_id'. Example: AUTH_ID1 to USERNAME5654 :) Sorry if my english is not unreadable :)

Comment: For this matter, you need to use joins. You have to join the `users` table and `log` table using the `auth_id` column. Here's a sample query:  


  `$username = \DB::table('users')->join('log', 'users.auth_id', 'log.auth_id')->select('users.username')->get();`  Try to refer to this link for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins

Comment: Oh everything works fine. But with username again i'm getting foreach not correctly. `$match->messages = DB::table('log')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->get();
$match->messages->username = DB::table('users')->join('log', 'users.steam_id', 'log.authid')->select('users.username')->get();` and foreach in my view: `@foreach ($match->messages as $message) @foreach ($match->messages->username as $username)
{{ $username->username }}:
{{ $message->message }}@endforeach
@endforeach`

Comment: Getting foreach result: `USERNAME1: LOG1 
USERNAME2: LOG1 
USERNAME1: LOG2 
USERNAME2: LOG2 `

Comment: There's no need for you to do 2 foreach. You can access the columns you need in both tables from the join you have made. Try this one.    `$matches = DB::table('users')->join('log', 'users.steam_id', 'log.authid')->select('users.username as username, log.authid as authid')->get();

@foreach ($matches as $match) 
  {{ $match->username }}: {{ $match->authid }}
@endforeach`

Comment: Getting error Undefined property: stdClass::$username

Comment: My bad, I misplaced quotation marks. Update the `select` part of the DB Query to this one: `select('users.username as username', 'log.authid as authid')`

Comment: Same thing. `$match->messages = DB::table('users')->join('log', 'users.steam_id', 'log.authid')->select('users.username as username', 'log.authid as authid')->get();`

Comment: Try this updated code: `$matches = DB::table('users')->join('log', 'users.steam_id', '=', 'log.authid')->select('users.username as username', 'log.authid as authid')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
$match->message = DB::table('log')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->get(['message','authid']);
@foreach ($match->message as $text)
{{ $text->authid }} {{ $text->message }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only two field data then you don't have to build two query in multiple variable you can do like below:

```
$data = DB::table('log')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->get(['authid','message']);

@if ($data)
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
        {{ $data[$i]->authid }} {{ $data[$i]->message }}
    @endfor
@endif
```

Using above code you will never get error in `foreach` if you didn't get data from `$data` variable